# Avoiding Float truncation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have an Active Record model that takes a `Float` attribute and a corresponding table:

```
# app/models/test.rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
end

# db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version:20150208185300)

  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "tests", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.float    "size"
  end

end
```

When I persist a Test everything looks fine:

```
Test.create(size: 271893999999.99997)
#=> #<Test id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-07 19:43:22", updated_at: "2015-02-07 19:43:22", size: 271893999999.99997>
```

However when retrieving the Test's size it comes back as truncated:

```
Test.last.size
#=> 271894000000.0
```

And was also truncated when persisted despite the misleading output when I created it:

```
Test.last
#=> #<Test id: 1, created_at: "2015-02-07 19:43:22", updated_at: "2015-02-07 19:43:22", size: 271894000000.0>
```

This problem perplexes me because I can do the following in Ruby:

```
a = 123456789.123456789
#=> 123456789.123456789
a.class
#=> Float
a
#=> 123456789.123456789
```

What are the limits of using `Float` in Rails/Postgres? Should I be using `Decimal` instead if I want the accuracy of 5 decimal points?

I am using Rails 4.1.1 and Postgres 9.3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the limits of using Float in Rails/Postgres?

PostgreSQL supports floating point numbers using the identifiers *float*,  *real*, and *double*. The identifiers *float* and *real* are synonyms. On most computers, *float* and *real* will give you at least 6 digits of decimal precision. This is what six digits of decimal precision looks like.

```
Test.last.size
#=> 271894000000.0
    ^^^^^^
```

On most computers, *double* will give you at least 15 digits of decimal precision. [Ruby's *float*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html) is equivalent to PostgreSQL's *double*, not to PostgreSQL's *real*.

> Should I be using Decimal instead if I want the accuracy of 5 decimal points?

The phrase *I want the accuracy of 5 decimal points* [sic] doesn't translate well into floating point data types. When you write something like this

```
Test.create(size: 271893999999.99997)
```

you're not asking PostgreSQL for five digits to the right of the decimal point. You're asking for 17 digits of decimal precision. A floating-point data type is unlikely to give you that much precision.

Instead of a float, you'll need to use an arbitrary-precision data type.  On the database side, it looks like

```
numeric(17, 5)
decimal(17, 5)
```

Both those declarations give you 17 digits of precision, with up to 5 digits to the right of the decimal point.

In a Rails migration, you might do something like this.

```
add_column :your_table, :your_column, :decimal, :precision => 17, :scale => 5
```

---

What you're seeing here

```
Test.last.size
#=> 271894000000.0
```

isn't truncation or rounding, strictly speaking. It's "error of approximation". The value `271893999999.99997` isn't in the database domain `float`, so PostgreSQL uses the closest value that *is* in that domain. That value happens to be `271894000000.0`.

---

[PostgreSQL numeric data types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Decimal` and specify *precision* and *scale* in your database, so that you are sure to have accurate calculations.

[Take a look at short example](https://ariejan.net/2012/08/28/rails-migrations-decimal-precision-and-scale/)

Comment: I still don't understand why I can't use Float for this task - they are able to handle that many decimals outside of Rails. Is this a Postgres limitation?